# I'm trying to delete a row in sqlite database according to column value passed in input

Tags: android, sqlite

delete method:

```
public void deleteData(String lat){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+COL1+"='"+lat+"'");
        db.close();
    }
```

when i check the database the targeted row  is not removed.
is there other possible solutions ?.any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`delete()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) method that's part of the `SQLiteDatabase` class:

```
public void deleteData(String lat) {
    final String where = String.format("%s=?",COL1);
    final String[] whereArgs = new String[] { lat };
    final int rowsDeleted = this.getWriteableDatabase().delete(TABLE_NAME, where, whereArgs);
    Log.d("MyTag", "Rows Deleted = " + rowsDeleted);
}
```